# Access NSMutableArray from other existing class

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to access a NSMutableArray from a different already existing class than it was created in. But if i NSLog it, i get null. My program starts up in class2, then I segue to class1, create my NSMutableArray by pressing one or more rows, and then I want my class2 to get the updated NSMutableArray instance, but all it get is null. Code below:

```
//class1.m

#import "FocusTagTableViewController.h"
#import "STATableViewController.h"

@implementation FocusTagTableViewController

@synthesize focusArray = _focusArray;
@synthesize allSelectedFocus = _allSelectedFocus;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
_focusArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Balance",@"Bevægelse",@"Elementskift",@"Vejrtrækning",@"Alle",nil];

[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *selectedFocus = [[_focusArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAppendingString:@","];
if(_allSelectedFocus == nil)
{
    _allSelectedFocus = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [_allSelectedFocus addObject:selectedFocus]; 
}
else if(![_allSelectedFocus containsObject:selectedFocus])
{
    [_allSelectedFocus addObject:selectedFocus];
}
}

//class2.m

#import "STATableViewController.h"
#import "FocusTagTableViewController.h"

@implementation STATableViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

 FocusTagTableViewController *focusTag = [[FocusTagTableViewController alloc]init];

[focustag addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"allSelectedFocus" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"allSelectedFocus"])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [object valueForKeyPath:keyPath]);
}
}
```

Comment: may be it's because you are trying to view the array elements right after you initialized your FocusTagTableViewController which at this point has an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in class 2 you create a new instance of class 1, wich has empty array.
If you want to access that array from class 2, you should make a reference to that first class. Or you could use Key-Value-Observing for that.

Here is the docs about KVO 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

In first class, when you create class two, add **self** as an observer for that array, and implement **observeValueForKeyPath:** method in class 1

Comment: I'm still relative new to objective-c. How would you use Key-Value-Observing for this problem?

Comment: I upgraded my code, but now i just get an error message: An instance 0x7e7e300 of class FocusTagTableViewController was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.

Comment: Than you have to retain it,when you move to another view controller

Comment: I happens as soon as i begin the app though, i never even change that view controller. Also i tried changing allSelectedFocus to retain, but it didn't help either. I never call RemoveObserver, could that be causing the problem?

Comment: Maybe,because than you may be observing it twice

Comment: Where els would I be observing it?

Comment: If you don't remove it and start observing again

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1) Import your class2.h file in your class1 file.

2) Create an `NSMutableArray *foo` globally in your class2.h file

3) create an object for class2 in your class1 file

4) instead Of using `allSelectedFocus` in your class1 file, set objects to `foo` in that file itself like this `[class2Object.foo addObject:selectedFocus];`

Comment: I would prefer not to make any global variables, so sadly that solution wouldn't work. Thanks though :)